# Gift someone something or gift someone with something

Tags: verbs

I would be thankful if you could let me know which one of the following self-made sentences mean the same as "I gift this book to you":

> - I gift you this book.
> - I gift you with this book.

I searched on the internet; there are both versions of the verb "gift". I mean:

> - [To gift someone something](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-gift-someone-something-through-flipkart-without-invoice-or-any-bill-on-the-delivery-box-and-with-no-mention-of-thing-inside-it)
> - [To gift someone with something](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gift)

I doubt which one is correct.

Actually in spite of the dictionaries definitions I doubt if using the noun "gift" as a verb sounds natural to AE natives or not. I have a specific dictionary which doesn't consider "gift" as a verb.

Comment: According to the dictionary [*gift*] as a verb is transitive, so I would go with "I gift you this book." But honestly I don't think many people (at least in the US) actually use *gift* this way.

Comment: What in the world is wrong with simply ***giving*** people things?

Comment: There are many simpler ways to say the same thing @Nihilist_Frost , but undoubtedly there was a reason behind my question! I was looking for a specific verb based on my mother language. :)

Comment: @A-friend Whatever your dictionary says, native speakers do know what "to gift" means. In fact, "re-gifting" is a well-known activity; see [**here.**](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/ronna-benjamin/give-me-a-present-not-a-regift_b_2279272.html) It is a jocular reference made popular a couple of decades ago by a TV comedy series called "Friends." Or was it "Seinfeld?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you want to say *I'm giving you X as a gift.*

A brief Google search will reveal that *gift* as a verb has been in use since the 17th century, but it does not mean the same as giving someone a gift.  At the very least *to gift* has IMHO a flavor of a process you are checking off a list of requirements or part of a procedure, and doesn't really have a warm, sentimental feeling of *giving a gift* to someone.

Especially "I gift you X" sounds really weird.

---

> I gift you this book.

This is correct.

> I gift you with this book.

This sounds like you are trying to say "I bless you with this book" - meaning you give the book as a blessing.

As weird as *I gift ...* sounds, this sounds 10 times weirder.  "With" wouldn't work with *give* like this, but it will kinda sorta work with *gift*.

You probably wanted to say "I gift this book to you" which is more correct.